# What special meaning has a hyphen in a javascript string?

Tags: javascript, string, truncate

I am working on something and I am trying to truncate a string that contains a hyphen as the last character.

```
str = "A-";
newstr = str.slice(0,1);
```

It should return "A", but it returns "A-" instead.

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hj7xg5st/5/)

You can update the tekst and the length of the string, but with the string "A-" and length 1 it keeps returning "A-"

Comment: You are supposed to return `newStr` in the fiddle. `slice` will not change the original string itself, as Strings are immutables in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You need an else condition to assign newStr to str when your length if condition is not met.  See where I have marked //new line

```
function truncate(str, num) {
  var numsub;
  var newStr;
  if(num >= 3 && str.length > 3 && str.length > num)
    numsub = num - 3;
  else
    numsub = num;

  newStr = str.slice(0, numsub).trim();

  if(str.length > 3 && str.length > num + 1)
    str = newStr + "...";
  else           //new line
    str= newStr; //new line
  return str;
}
 document.write(truncate("A-", 1));
```

working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hj7xg5st/6/

Comment: hey @Eric Philips  Yeah, I just figured that out for myself too. Stupid rookie mistake on my part